# Algorithm for auto generated series number in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to make an algorithm for generate next series number by specified last series number in sql like below:

```
     Last Number   Next Number
>      AAAA095       AAAA096
>      AAAA999       AAAB001
>      AAAB001       AAAB002
>      AAAZ999       AABA001
```

Comment: Interesting. Good luck! Let us know how you get on...

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using.

Comment: looks to me that your number is actually two values - one is a base 26 number (using just alpha characters) with length 4, the second is a decimal number of length three.  You need to think about how you increment each of these elements - show us what you managed to do so far and we may be able to help

Comment: Added `sql-server` tag based on the solution provided

Comment: thanks all,
i increase each of three digits to 999 & after that reset to 001 and increase  alpha number one step
this algorithm  make 45,65,19,024 series

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some try, Finally i got an algorithm & create it to SQL Scalar-valued function for this question as below

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetNextSeries ( @lastSeriesNo VARCHAR(8))
RETURNS VARCHAR(8)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @nextSeriesNo VARCHAR(8)
    DECLARE @CHAR1 CHAR=SUBSTRING(@lastSeriesNo,1,1)
    DECLARE @CHAR2 CHAR=SUBSTRING(@lastSeriesNo,2,1)
    DECLARE @CHAR3 CHAR=SUBSTRING(@lastSeriesNo,3,1)
    DECLARE @CHAR4 CHAR=SUBSTRING(@lastSeriesNo,4,1)
    DECLARE @n INT=SUBSTRING(@lastSeriesNo,5,3)

    SET @n = @n + 1
    IF(@n>999)
    BEGIN
        SET @n=1
        IF(@CHAR4<>'Z')
        BEGIN
            SET @CHAR4=CHAR(UNICODE(@CHAR4)+1)
        END
        ELSE IF(@CHAR3<>'Z')
        BEGIN
            SET @CHAR4='A'
            SET @CHAR3=CHAR(UNICODE(@CHAR3)+1)
        END
        ELSE IF(@CHAR2<>'Z')
        BEGIN
            SET @CHAR4='A'
            SET @CHAR3='A'
            SET @CHAR2=CHAR(UNICODE(@CHAR2)+1)
        END
        ELSE IF(@CHAR1<>'Z')
        BEGIN
            SET @CHAR4='A'
            SET @CHAR3='A'
            SET @CHAR2='A'
            SET @CHAR1=CHAR(UNICODE(@CHAR1)+1)
        END
    END

    SET @nextSeriesNo=@CHAR1+@CHAR2+@CHAR3+@CHAR4+(CASE LEN(@n) WHEN 1 THEN '00' WHEN 2 THEN '0' ELSE '' END)+convert(VARCHAR(3),@n) 
    RETURN @nextSeriesNo
END
```